# Literature on linguistics education

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for recently published journals or books dealing with Linguistics education, or the training of professional linguists. I have found one journal, "Innovations in Linguistics Education," which doesn't appear to be regularly published anymore.

Comment: I don't know of any. It's like any other apprenticeship system; you do what your advisors tell you to do. And they make it up because they **know.**

Comment: I don't have an answer to your question, but I was wondering about the authors at "Innovations in Linguistics Education". Do you know where the people whose works you liked there publish now?

Comment: Teaching Linguistics

I just found a notice for a new journal (no issues published yet)
http://elanguage.net/journals/index.php/teachinglinguistics/index

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about linguistics education, not linguistics itself.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann let it slide, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Teaching linguistics: reflections on practice*](http://www.equinoxpub.com/equinox/books/showbook.asp?bkid=421&keyword=Kuiper) by Koenraad Kuiper (ed.) might be useful. It's in publication by Equinox Publishers. I've never studied this as a teaching practice, so I'm afraid I'm not sure how relevant a resource it will be for your purposes.

Comment: I had a brief search of my University library for you, and I also saw _Applied Linguistics and Primary School Teaching_ by Ellis and McCartney and I also found _Applied linguistics and English language teaching_ by (eds.) Bowers and Brumfit. Sorry if this is not the kind of thing you were looking for.

Comment: The Kuiper ed. book I think is just the thing I am looking for. I've asked my library to purchase it for me.